# error: invalid use of incomplete type with forward declaration

Tags: c++, arduino-c++

I am trying to tidy up a series of spaghetti code derived from an Arduino project dealing with wifi, mqtt ans SPIFF stored configuration and the easiest solution I found is to have a base class which contains pointers to subclasses each of which has a pointer to the parent class and when needed can call the base class and its pointers to objects.

In this SSCCE I have 2 classes A and B where B is contained in A and when required can access a method of A.

```
a.h
#include<stdio.h>

class B;

class A
{
    public:
        A();
        B* b;
        void readConf();
};
```

---

```
a.c
#include "a.h"

A::A()
{
}

void A::readConf()
{
    //readconf
}
```

---

```
b.h
#include<stdio.h>

class A;

class B
{
    private:
        A* parent;
    public:
        B(A*);
        void fun();
};
```

---

```
b.c
#include "b.h"

B::B(A* a):
parent(a)
{
};

void B::fun()
{
    parent->readConf(); // this call to the parent method raises the error
}
```

---

```
test.c
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

int main()
{
    A a = A();
    return 0;
}
```

As soon as I compile it though I have a:

> gcc -c a.c -o a.o
> gcc -c b.c -o b.o b.c: In member function
> ‘void B::fun()’: b.c:11:8: error: invalid use of incomplete type
> ‘class A’    11 |  parent->readConf();
> |        ^~ In file included from b.c:1: b.h:3:7: note: forward declaration of ‘class A’
> 3 | class A;
> |       ^

reading other threads I realized a forward declaration of A is not sufficient because the class B needs to know the complete definition of A to call one of its methods, however including the header files in both a.h and b.h creates a circular dependency, how can I make the above work without sacrificing my design of a base class containing pointers to other classes which can call the parent and its objects methods through a pointer to the base class?

Comment: Why did you tag this with both C and C++? Also, please check out https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=invalid+use+of+incomplete+type.

Comment: `b.c` needs `#include "a.h"`  (and the file extension should not be `.c` really)

Comment: Including `a.h` in `b.c` would not create a circular dependency.

Comment: suggest using arduino-c++ tag (the language is an emaciated dialect of C++)

Comment: In Arduino the files are compiled with gcc and linked with g++, the above SSCCE is valid both as c and c++ source files. It really doesn't matter.

Comment: What it's compiled with doesn't change the fact that the language you are using is C++.

Comment: As written, `test.c` does not need to include `"b.h"` as only class `A` is used from that file.

Answer (score 0):

`b.c` (should be .cpp, IMHO) needs to know `a`'s full definition in order to dereference it through the pointer.  Without this information, it has no idea how to find whatever it is that you expect to find at that address.

You therefore need to #include "a.h" to get that definition, from inside b.cpp.